# jquery animate doesn't work in IE9 and older

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have problem with jquery animation. It's not working in IE9 and older. I think problem is somewhere with css because as I can see in a ie there is opacity set to 0.

### Javascript

```
var $lead = $('.lead');
var height = $lead.height();
var totalHeight = height * numOfLeads;
function bounce() {
    var time = 400;
    var counter1 = 1;
    $($(".lead").get().reverse()).each(function() {
        setTimeout(function(el, counter1, height, totalHeight) {
            $(el).css({
                top: "-" + (totalHeight - (counter1 * height) + height) + "px",
                opacity: 0,
                display: "block",
                position: "relative"
            }).animate({
                top: "+=" + (totalHeight - (counter1 * height) + height) + "px",
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce")
                    ;
        }, time, this, counter1, height, totalHeight);
        time += 400;
        counter1 += 1;
    });
}
bounce();
```

### HTML

```
<div class="lead">
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div>
        <span class="first green end"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="last"></span>
    </div>
    <span>Accepted</span>
</div>
<div class="product">Hypotek</div>
<div class="county">Ustecky</div>
<div class="change">
    <span>Changed</span>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>29</div>
    <div>38</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#leads{position: absolute;}
#leads, #leads div { z-index: 5;}
.lead { background: url("../images/lead_back_stripe.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent; height: 65px;}
.lead > div { float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 21px; width: 180px;}
.lead > div.progress-bar{width: 185px;}
.lead > div.product {width: 175px;}
```

You can see the whole thing [here](http://honzuvklient.chytryhonza.cz/)

**Does anybody know where the problem is?**

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? If 2+, then thats probably your reason

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding ..jQuery v1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long story short: opacity won't work in ie and the only method to set an opacity in ie is, as far as i know, `filter: alpha(opacity = X);` with 0 < X > 100  ....which won't work with an jquery animation

except, maybe this works:

```
$(el).animate({
        opacity:1
},{
    step: function( now, fx ) {
        var X = 100 * now; //like at half the animation, opacity is 0.5, so X becomes 50
        $(fx.elem).css("filter","alpha(opacity="+X+")");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any other way how to get the effect?

Comment: hmm..maybe a manual function for the animation...with `.css("filter","alpha(opacity="+X+")")` ...editing answer

Comment: thanks but I used static version for IE ....who uses IE doesn't deserve any nice effects!!